# How can I have WPF use one window style for Debug mode and another for Release mode?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have two different styles for my window:

1. Regular - window has title bar and can be moved/resized
2. Fixed - window has no title bar and is fixed at the center of the screen

The window is too wide for either of the monitors on my development machine, but it's a perfect fit for the target/install machine. So, when debugging, I need to be able to move the Window so I can see everything on it, but when I release the app, I need it to run in "full screen" mode (like a PowerPoint app in projector mode).

Is there any way to set the `Style` property of the window based on whether I'm compiling in Debug vs. Release mode? I was thinking I might be able to use a binding, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create a Style picker class:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class DebugReleaseStylePicker
    {
        #if DEBUG
                internal static readonly bool debug = true;
        #else
        internal static readonly bool debug=false;
        #endif

        public Style ReleaseStyle
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public Style DebugStyle
        {
            get; set;
        }


        public Style CurrentStyle
        {
            get
            {
                return debug ? DebugStyle : ReleaseStyle;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in your App.xaml
add to your Application.Resources your debug and release style + a instance of the StylePicker and set the ReleaseStyle and DebugStyle to the previous set up styles:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="WindowDebugStyle">
            <Setter Property="Window.Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="WindowReleaseStyle">
            <Setter Property="Window.Background" Value="Blue"></Setter>
        </Style>

        <WpfApplication1:DebugReleaseStylePicker x:Key="stylePicker"
            ReleaseStyle="{StaticResource WindowReleaseStyle}"
            DebugStyle="{StaticResource WindowDebugStyle}"/>
    </Application.Resources>
```

In your Window markup set up the WindowStyle like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300"
        Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource stylePicker}, Path=CurrentStyle}">  
..
</Window>
```

You can reuse the DebugReleaseStylePicker to set the style to any other control not just the Window.

Comment: I really like the flexibility of this solution. I could see using a similar technique in other areas too. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

It may be hard to do it in XAML, but in actual code you could just do something like:

```
#if DEBUG
    window.Style = WindowStyles.Regular;
#endif
```

Why not put that somewhere that will be executed after the normal XAML code has been executed?

Comment: I followed this and it is one approach that works. I did find that the code was `WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow` as the code didn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

You could create a markup extension like this one:

```
public class DebugStyleExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public object DebugResourceKey { get; set; }
    public object ReleaseResourceKey { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
#if DEBUG
        return Application.Current.FindResource(DebugResourceKey) as Style;
#else
        return Application.Current.FindResource(ReleaseResourceKey) as Style
#endif
    }
}
```

you would use it like that :

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
        Style="{my:DebugStyle DebugResourceKey=DebugStyle, ReleaseResourceKey=NormalStyle}">
```

Comment: I like this, but it won't compile: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Application.FindResource(object)'` The offending code is `Application.FindResource`. Does this class file need to be in the same assembly as my App? Thx.

Comment: I just fixed the code (`Application.Current.FindResource` rather that `Application.FindResource`)

Comment: It can be in the same assembly or in another one. If it is in a different assembly, you must specify the assembly name in the xmlns declaration

Comment: Thanks for fixing that. I'm noticing one other problem, though I don't think it has anything to do with your code. The line of code immediately following the `#else` is showing up in gray text and not responding to intellisense. Any idea what could be causing this? Thanks again.

Comment: That's because you're in debug mode. The editor knows that this code won't be compiled (because the DEBUG symbol is defined), so it shows it as "disabled code".

Comment: Ohh :) That makes a lot of sense, except I don't get why intellisense wouldn't work.

Comment: I guess the editor handles it as a "not code" section, like comments... if you want to edit this part, switch to release mode ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can do conditional compilation in the XAML file as well as the codebehind.
[check out this article](http://www.removingalldoubt.com/PermaLink.aspx/defa2a7d-b1e9-49eb-b8c8-438348be8d18)

basically, you do like this in your Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
#if BETA
[assembly:XmlnsDefinition("BetaVersion", "Example.Technology")]
#endif
```

add your xmlns to the *.XAML file:

```
xmlns:beta="BetaVersion"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
```

now, you can do like this:

```
<mc:Choice Requires="beta">
  <Label>
    This is ALPHA software. Confidential.
    Internal use only. Do not distribute
  <Label>
</mc:Choice>
```

as a side note, this probably wont work with silverlight--AFIK the `assembly:XmlnsDefinition` is not supported

Comment: as a side note, the XmlnsDefinition has been added to silverlight as of version 4

Comment: The article is broken unfortunately

Comment: There are a number of alternative tutorials to the linked article. Just use your favorite Internet search to look for _`http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006`_ and "conditional compilation".

Answer (score 0):

Could you use an #if DEBUG to set a property to a different value and bind to it?

Maybe

```
#if DEBUG
style = 0;
#else
style = 1;
#endif
```

(Bear in mind I don't have VS here.)  and use a valueconverter.

Comment: Beaten by Mr. Skeet and his was nicer, too!  Damn!

Answer (score 0):

Lots of helpful answers...I thought of another idea I thought I'd throw out there: a value converter plus a binding:

**Here's the value converter:**

```
    public class WindowToWindowStyle : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var window = (Window)value;
            var style = (Style)window.FindResource("Window_FixedStyle");
#if DEBUG
            style = (Style)window.FindResource("Window_Style");
#endif
            return style;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }
    }
```

**Here's my Window declaration:**

```
<Window
    ...
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProj"
    Style="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource ValueConverter_WindowToWindowStyle}}"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:WindowToWindowStyle
            x:Key="ValueConverter_WindowToWindowStyle" />
    </Window.Resources>
    ...
</Window>
```

**What this does:**

So, what's going on here is that I pass a reference to the Window itself into the value converter, and it returns the appropriate style.